# Javascript How to deal with NaNs when adding and averaging values in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write an efficient javascript function that will loop through a table, grab all numbers, and ignore all tds with strings. The columns will be added and averaged, and rows will be appended for each.

I have the basic functionality for this working. Whereas, if the table does not include a string, the results are as expected. When the table does include a string, the total and average of the column are way off and I'm not exactly sure how the answer is being calculated. I'm hoping somebody can help me figure out a way to ignore these values all together, and create a more efficient way of writing this function.

Finally, I want to be able to call this function by simply passing in the table, e.g. `buildRows(table)`;

Here's what I got so far:

```js
// function to build total and average rows
function buildRow($element) {
    var result = [];
    $($element).find('tbody tr').each(function() {
      // Ignore the first column reserved for labels
      $('td:not(:first)', this).each(function(index, val) {
        if (!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
        result[index] += parseInt($(val).text());
      });
    });
    // Get the total amount rows
    var rowCount = $($element).find('tbody tr').length;
    // Add Average Row
    $($element).append('<tr class="avg-row"></tr>');
    $($element).find('tr').last().append('<td>' + 'Averages' + '</td>');
    $(result).each(function() {
        $($element).find('tr').last().append('<td class="avg-td">' + this / rowCount + '</td>');
    });
    // Add Total Row
    $($element).append('<tr class="total-row"></tr>');
    $($element).find('tr').last().append('<td>' + 'Totals' + '</td>');
    $(result).each(function() {
        $($element).find('tr').last().append('<td class="total-td">' + this + '</td>');
    });        
}

// ideal function calls
var tableOne = $('.tableOne');
buildRow(tableOne);
var tableTwo = $('.tableTwo');
buildRow(tableTwo);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableOne">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>23.356</td>  
    <td>88</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>    
    <td>111440.568</td>
    <td>115555</td>
    <td>4.21598</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Three</td>    
    <td>27</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>144487.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Four</td>    
    <td>23.356</td> 
    <td>125%</td>   
    <td>778978523.36</td>   
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTwo">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>    
    <td>45</td>
    <td>23.356</td>  
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>    
    <td>111440.568</td>
    <td>115555</td>
    <td>4.21598</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Three</td>    
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>144487.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Four</td>    
    <td>23.356</td> 
    <td>125%</td>   
    <td>778978523.36</td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first table with no strings seems okay, 2nd table the results are way off and I'm not sure how the totals are being calculated.

Comment: What result are you expecting for a column with non-numbers? Should non-numbers be treated as 0? Should they be included when calculating the average?

Comment: Is the switch between floats and ints intentional?

Comment: @Jordan I would prefer to skip it entirely, and not treat it as a value of 0.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is intentional as I'll never know what sort of number values will be coming in to these tables.

Comment: So you want to intentionally drop the non-integer part of floats? I'm asking again because I'm not sure if you understood my question. Also, what's the difference between skipping it and calling it zero? Other than you don't have to run the conditional?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just do `parseInt` on every value, it sometimes transform a string to a weird number. You have to check if it is not a valid number before you sum it up. I think of a regex or something like that, untested.

```
var v = $(val).text();
if(v.match(/^[\s0-9\.]+$/)){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using jQuery why not just use jQuery's built in is numeric condition check function `$.isNumeric` which will parse out pretty much all the data you don't want.

```
// true (numeric)
$.isNumeric( "-10" )
$.isNumeric( "0" )
$.isNumeric( 0xFF )
$.isNumeric( "0xFF" )
$.isNumeric( "8e5" )
$.isNumeric( "3.1415" )
$.isNumeric( +10 )
$.isNumeric( 0144 )

// false (non-numeric)
$.isNumeric( "-0x42" )
$.isNumeric( "7.2acdgs" )
$.isNumeric( "" )
$.isNumeric( {} )
$.isNumeric( NaN )
$.isNumeric( null )
$.isNumeric( true )
$.isNumeric( Infinity )
$.isNumeric( undefined )
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1d9Lbnp1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether td value has integer or not by using `var reg = /^\d+$/;`

Answer (score 0):

You could just ignore the `Nan`s and use `Number` instead of `parseInt` if you want something more accurate:

```
 $('td:not(:first)', this).each(function(index, val) {
        if (!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
        var num = Number($(val).text());
        num = isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
        result[index] += num;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to remember:

1. `parseFloat` will capture floats and integers
2. When working with numbers, you can use the `||0` to hack ignore the falsy values, replacing them with a `0`

Other than that, I took some liberties with your code, putting the necessary elements in variables:

```js
// function to build total and average rows
function buildRow($table) {
  var result = [],
      $tbody = $table.find('tbody'),
      $rows  = $tbody.find('tr'),
      row_count = $rows.length;
  
  $rows.each(function() {
    // Ignore the first column reserved for labels
    var $cells = $('td:not(:first)',this);
    $cells.each(function(index,cell) {
      if (!result[index]) 
        result[index] = 0;
      result[index] += parseFloat($(cell).text()||0);
    });
  });
  
  // Add Average Row
  var $avg_row = $('<tr class="avg-row"></tr>');
  $avg_row.append('<td>Averages</td>');
  $.each(result,function() {
    $avg_row.append('<td class="avg-td">' + ( this / row_count ) + '</td>');
  });
  $tbody.append($avg_row);
  
  // Add Total Row
  var $total_row = $('<tr class="total-row"></tr>');
  $total_row.append('<td>Totals</td>');
  $.each(result,function() {
    $total_row.append('<td class="total-td">' + this + '</td>');
  });
  $tbody.append($total_row);
}

// ideal function calls
var $tableOne = $('.tableOne');
buildRow($tableOne);
var $tableTwo = $('.tableTwo');
buildRow($tableTwo);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableOne">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>88</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
    <td>111440.568</td>
    <td>115555</td>
    <td>4.21598</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Three</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>144487.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Four</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>125%</td>
    <td>778978523.36</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTwo">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
    <td>111440.568</td>
    <td>115555</td>
    <td>4.21598</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Three</td>
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>144487.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Four</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>125%</td>
    <td>778978523.36</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do the same thing, by retrieving the values first by column (using `nth-child`) and then using `reduce` to calculate sums:

```js
['.tableOne', '.tableTwo'].forEach(function(tbl){
  makeAggregates($(tbl));
});

function makeAggregates($tbl) {
  var $tbody = $tbl.find('tbody');
  var sums = sumOfColumns($tbody);

  var $total_row = $('<tr class="total-row"><td class="total-td">Total</td></tr>');
  var $average_row = $('<tr class="avg-row"><td class="avg-td">Averages</td></tr>');

  $.each(sums, function(key,col) {
    var total = col[1],
      items = col[0];
    $total_row.append('<td class="total-row">' + total + '</td>');
    $average_row.append('<td class="avg-row">' + total / items + '</td>');
  });
  
  $tbody.append($average_row,$total_row);
}

function sumOfColumns($tbody) {
  var $rows = $tbody.find('tr');

  // Get number of columns
  var num_cols = $rows.first().find('td').length;

  var col_sums = {};
  for (var col = 2; col < num_cols + 1; col++) {
    var $col_data = $tbody.find('td:nth-child(' + col + ')'),
      arr_values = $col_data.map(function() {
        return this.textContent
      }).get();

    col_sums[col - 1] = [
      arr_values.length,
      arr_values.reduce(function(pv, cv) {
        return pv + (parseFloat(cv) || 0)
      }, 0)
    ];
  }

  return col_sums;
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableOne">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>88</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
    <td>111440.568</td>
    <td>115555</td>
    <td>4.21598</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Three</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>144487.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Four</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>125%</td>
    <td>778978523.36</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTwo">
  <tr>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
    <td>111440.568</td>
    <td>115555</td>
    <td>4.21598</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Three</td>
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>144487.11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Four</td>
    <td>23.356</td>
    <td>125%</td>
    <td>778978523.36</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the trick is to check if the value is a number before using it in your calculations. That's as easy as `isNaN(parseInt(string))`.

Overall I think you can simplify your code a lot by extracting the (good) data from the table into arrays of numbers (one array for each column). You can see that in the `getData` function in the below snippet. Then it's a simple matter of iterating over each column's data to calculate its total and average.

You can also simplify things by using semantic markup: `<tbody>` for your data, `<th>` for heading cells, and `<tfoot>` for the Averages and Totals rows. This makes both extracting the data and styling the output much easier.

Here's how it looks with jQuery. Mind you, my jQuery's a bit rusty. At the end of the post you'll find another snippet sans jQuery, which is only slightly more verbose.

### jQuery

```js
function getData($rows) {
  return $('td', $rows[0]).toArray().map((_, idx) =>
    $rows.toArray().reduce((result, row) => {
      const value = parseInt($('td', row)[idx].innerText, 10);
      return result.concat(isNaN(value) ? [] : value);
    }, [])
  );
}

function generateRow(label, values, precision=3) {
  const mult = Math.pow(10, precision);
  return $(`<tr><th>${label}</th></tr>`).append(
    values.map(val => $(`<td>${Math.round(val * mult) / mult}</td>`)));
}

function aggregateData($table) {
  const averages = [];
  const totals = [];
  
  getData($table.find('tbody tr')).forEach(values => {
    const total = values.reduce((total, val) => (total + val), 0);
    totals.push(total);
    averages.push(total / values.length);
  });

  $('<tfoot>').append(
    generateRow('Averages', averages),
    generateRow('Totals', totals)
  ).appendTo($table)
}

aggregateData($('.tableOne'));
aggregateData($('.tableTwo'));
```

```css
table { width: 300px; margin-bottom: 1em; border: 1px solid gray; }
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
td, th { padding: 7px; text-align: center; }
tfoot tr { background-color: paleturquoise; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableOne">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>300</td>  
      <td>6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Two</th>    
      <td>20</td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>7000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Three</th>    
      <td>30</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>8000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Four</th>    
      <td>40</td> 
      <td>600</td>   
      <td>9000</td>   
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tableTwo">
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>    
    <td>10</td>
    <td>300</td>  
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Two</th>    
    <td>20</td>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>7000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Three</th>    
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>8000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Four</th>    
    <td>40</td> 
    <td>600</td>   
    <td>9000</td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

### No jQuery

```js
function getData(rows) {
  const numCols = rows[0].querySelectorAll('td').length;
  return new Array(numCols).fill().map((_, idx) =>
    Array.prototype.reduce.call(rows, (result, row) => {
      const value = parseInt(row.querySelectorAll('td')[idx].innerText, 10);
      return result.concat(isNaN(value) ? [] : value);
    }, [])
  );
}

function generateRow(label, values, precision=3) {
  const mult = Math.pow(10, precision);
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  row.innerHTML = values.reduce((html, val) => html + `<td>${Math.round(val * mult) / mult}</td>`, `<th>${label}</th>`);
  return row;
}

function aggregateData(table) {
  const totals = [];
  const averages = [];

  getData(table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach(values => {
    const total = values.reduce((total, val) => (total + val), 0);
    totals.push(total);
    averages.push(total / values.length);
  });
  
  const tfoot = document.createElement('tfoot');
  tfoot.appendChild(generateRow('Averages', averages));
  tfoot.appendChild(generateRow('Totals', totals));;
  table.appendChild(tfoot);
}

aggregateData(document.querySelector('.tableOne'));
aggregateData(document.querySelector('.tableTwo'));
```

```css
table { width: 300px; margin-bottom: 1em; border: 1px solid gray; }
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
td, th { padding: 7px; text-align: center; }
tfoot tr { background-color: paleturquoise; }
```

```html
<table class="tableOne">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>One</th>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>300</td>  
      <td>6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Two</th>    
      <td>20</td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>7000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Three</th>    
      <td>30</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>8000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Four</th>    
      <td>40</td> 
      <td>600</td>   
      <td>9000</td>   
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tableTwo">
  <tr>
    <th>One</th>    
    <td>10</td>
    <td>300</td>  
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Two</th>    
    <td>20</td>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>7000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Three</th>    
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>8000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Four</th>    
    <td>40</td> 
    <td>600</td>   
    <td>9000</td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```